# return is undefined JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question??.Why this function return value is undefined. i don't understand.

Help to solve me please.

[image]

Comment: Post your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: ^^ why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 (We would also need to see more of it, but you're probably looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: There's not enough code provided to make that determination...at the very least provide the entire function

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: A return in a callback does not return to the outer function

Comment: @charlietfl: Particularly not when the outer function has already returned. :-D

Answer (score -1):

Because you're trying to `return` from a callback function's scope, which doesn't return to the outer function's scope. This is a pretty common mistake.

You should find another way to write this function so the query functions are in the same scope. Maybe use `Promise`s or `async`-`await`?